# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client.edge'

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, module

I'm trying to use server components with nextJS but I get an error when I want to use "use server" in my component.

`./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/action-client-wrapper.js:21:37
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-server-dom-webpack/client.edge'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./components/template/Template.tsx
./pages/index.tsx`

Template.tsx

```
"use server";

import Header from "../header/Header";
import Footer from "../footer/Footer";

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  sliders?: React.JSX.Element;
};

const Template = ({ children = null, sliders }: Props) => {
  let isServer = typeof window !== "undefined" ? true : false;
  console.log(isServer);

  return (
    <div className="min-w-screen  min-h-screen bg-[#F8F9FA] overflow-hidden relative">
      <div
        className={` ${
          sliders != undefined ? "h-4.75xl" : "h-full"
        }    overflow-hidden`}
      >
        <Header slidersExist={sliders} />
        {sliders !== null && sliders}
      </div>
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Template;
```

Condif next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "blog-next-prisma-v2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.2.0",
    "@uidotdev/usehooks": "^2.1.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "postcss": "8.4.28",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "swiper": "^10.2.0",
    "swr": "^2.2.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.5.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "prisma": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Error on the website

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slORC.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve this?

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't using the router app and was still using the old version of routing. I migrated my project to nextjs with the router app and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the new app router from Next.js
Instead of using the normal pages router
Not sure what caused this but this fixed the issue for me and i was able to build the app
Here is a link to next js documentation just follow this and probably migrate your project accordingly :
https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/installation
[Here is a refrence image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXA3O.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using pages route ,  you should migrate to app route , there are all components server side rendering by default here is the docs : https://nextjs.org/docs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).